# After updating plugin role strategy plugin, jenkins is not working

Tags: jenkins

I'm using `jenkins` 2.138.1. And I have updated [role-based strategy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) in "manage plugin" section and tried to restart the instance using `jenkinsurl/restart`. It is throwing below error and now no login screen is visible:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategyat com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:79)atcom.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at hudson.util.XStream2$CompatibilityMapper.realClass(XStream2.java:379)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at org.jenkinsci.jruby.JRubyMapper.realClass(JRubyMapper.java:34)
        at hudson.util.xstream.MapperDelegate.realClass(MapperDelegate.java:43)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:48)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.determineType(RobustReflectionConverter.java:461)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:327)
    Caused: jenkins.util.xstream.CriticalXStreamException: com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy : com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy
    ---- Debugging information ----
    message             : com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy
    cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
    cause-message       : com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy
    class               : hudson.model.Hudson
    required-type       : hudson.model.Hudson
    converter-type      : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
    path                : /hudson/authorizationStrategy
    line number         : 11
    version             : not available
    -------------------------------
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:356)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:270)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1189)
        at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:161)
        at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:132)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1173)
        at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:178)
    Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
        at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:181)
        at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:161)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.loadConfig(Jenkins.java:3005)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.access$1300(Jenkins.java:304)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$13.run(Jenkins.java:3104)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1066)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:282)
        at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:48)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1100)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:904)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:233)
    Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:250)
```

Answer (score 19):

Had the same problem, solved this way:

I closed the jenkins url as this makes it usable but everybody becomes admin

Backed up the config.xml as it will be blanked out.

In `$JENKINS_HOME/config.xml` commented out/removed all the `authorizationStrategy` block and changed `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` to false.

Started jenkins (it started back normally but without authentication.

Changed the config.xml to previous original version (included all security previously running) and worked back normally with the original role strategy configuration in place.

Comment: Here is the easy way to rebuild your config file, after moving the original aside:
`xq -x 'del(.hudson.authorizationStrategy)' /var/lib/jenkins/config_orig.xml > /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml`

xq is provided by and provides a wrapper around jq.  See:
https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/#xml-support

Answer (score 2):

I had this error today, in my case was an issue of dependencies, the [Role-based Authorization Strategy](https://github.com/jenkinsci/role-strategy-plugin/releases/tag/role-strategy-3.0) was updated to v3.0 and I updated the plugins with [Ansible jenkins_job module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/jenkins_job_module.html) and Jenkins failed after restart.
Error from browser was similar to this, I got this error from server:

```
2020-06-10 20:02:24.483+0000 [id=29]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Role-based Authorization Strategy v3.0 (role-strategy)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Role-based Authorization Strategy (3.0)
 - Plugin is missing: extended-read-permission (3.2)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:933)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:546)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1133)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

As you see, there is a pending plugin, seems that Ansible can update plugins from dependencies as required, but not install newer dependencies.

After setting similar solution, making backup of config.xml, removing security, installing dependency [Extended Read Permission](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-read-permission/) and then restoring config I was able to restore the service.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error `(rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy)` for jenkins running on my windows local machine.
[I got the same error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjaUw.jpg)

- Go to Jenkins folder on your C Drive where Jenkins is installed.
- Try to find config.xml file in your local machine.
- It could be either in this location
  "`C:\Programfiles\Jenkins\.jenkins\config.xml`"  Or
  "`C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\config.xml`"
- Remember that .jenkins folder is hide by default on windows machine so first unhide all the folders and then go inside "`C:\Programfiles\Jenkins\`" or "`C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\`"
- I am sure you will be able to find config.xml file in the above mentioned path or directly search on your windows for config.xml file.
- Once you found `config.xml`,
- First try to take a backup of `config.xml` file and paste it somewhere and keep it safely with you.
- Close all the `Jenkins url (Localhost:8080)` on browser
- Now go to windows > search `"Services"` on windows > [Please check this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLgAG.png)
- **Search for Jenkins and `then right click on jenkins and click on STOP`** [Please check the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMWna.png)
- Now go to `config.xml` open with Notepad and **commented out/removed all the `<authorizationStrategy>`Block** and changed `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` to `<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>`.
- Save the `config.xml` file
- Again Go back to `Services` search **`Jenkins`** and **`start`** the **`service`**
- **`Go to Browser and run the localhost:8080 again and it worked`**.
- Started jenkins (it started back normally but without authentication).

Changed the config.xml to previous original version (included all security previously running) and worked back normally with the original role strategy configuration in place.

> **Finally Solved** !!!!!!!!

---

- If this error comes on LINUX Machines then please check the below Youtube Link for the solution. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kn4VwdVB0fs&ab_channel=AmanShukla

> **Thanks to everyone in AWS Linux DevOps Community.**

Answer (score -3):

Check ownership of /var/lib/jenkins.
make sure the owner is jenkins.

```
chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins
```

This resolved my problem.